# Is it a good practice to use Wait inside Task.Factory.StartNew();

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous

I have this method in my MyViewModel:

```
private void Initialise()
{
    IsBusy = true;
    
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        try
        {
            LoadTitles()
            .ContinueWith(t => LoadNationalities())
            .Wait();
        }
        catch (AggregateException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }).ContinueWith(task => IsBusy = false);
}
```

The problem I face is, I want to set focus to a given TextBox, and the focus gets set, but with that inner Wait() method, the focus moves somewhere else, after I suppose the Wait() method is done waiting

```
private void MyView_Loaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Keyboard.Focus(txtHouse);
        FocusManager.SetFocusedElement(this, txtHouse);
        txtHouse.Focus();
        txtHouse.Select(0, 0);
    }
```

Comment: Just use `await` to add continuations to things.  Using `ContinueWith` properly is *much* harder to do correctly in most situations.

Comment: @Servy await where in my case?

Comment: Anywhere you want to do something after an asynchronous operation has finished.

Comment: @Servy why Wait() is causing trouble, even IsComplete doesn't work.

Comment: If you see Wait or ContinueWith: that is already legacy code and should not be used. And no, you should not call Wait() - you should `await`

Comment: You shouldn't be waiting in the first place, given that you're trying to be doing this asynchronously.  It makes no sense to create a new thread just to have it sit there and do nothing the entire time.  You're chasing a red herring.

Comment: No, it's not a good practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method should probably be implemented like shown below, without Task.Factory.StartNew, ContinueWith and Wait.

```
private async Task InitialiseAsync()
{
    IsBusy = true;

    try
    {
        await LoadTitlesAsync();
        await LoadNationalitiesAsync();
    }
    finally
    {
        IsBusy = false;
    }
}
```

and be awaited when called:

```
await x.InitialiseAsync();
```

Comment: Is this going to work well with IsBusy, I mean, Is IsBusy will get set to false when both tasks in the Try block get finished?

Comment: Yes, and the try/catch was not even necessary.

Comment: `try/finally` may be required, to ensure that the `IsBusy` will become false eventually.